# Proper way to filter a table using values in another table in MS Access?

Tags: database, performance, ms-access

I have a table of transactions with some transaction IDs and Employee Numbers. I have two other tables which are basically just a column full of transactions or employees that need to be filtered out from the first.

I have been running my query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TransactionMaster 
Where TransactionMaster.TransID 
NOT IN (SELECT TransID from BadTransactions) 
AND etc...(repeat for employee numbers)
```

I have noticed slow performance when running these types of queries. I am wondering if there is a better way to build this query?

Comment: Use a RIGHT JOIN instead of the subselect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all `TransactionMaster` rows which don't include a `TransID` match in `BadTransactions`, use a `LEFT JOIN` and ask for only those rows where `BadTransactions.TransID Is Null` (unmatched).

```sql
SELECT tm.*
FROM
    TransactionMaster AS tm
    LEFT JOIN
    BadTransactions AS bt
    ON tm.TransID = bt.TransID 
WHERE bt.TransID Is Null;
```

That query should be relatively fast with `TransID` indexed.

If you have Access available, create a new query using the "unmatched query wizard".  It will guide you through the steps to create a similar query.

Comment: Thanks! This was much faster.